Frame animation flickers on js (cordova)
I am writing an application in js using cordova.
I have a frame animation that consists of 75 frames. I preload the frames and start creating the animation, my class is responsible for this:


export class AnimFrameAll {
    anim;
    nameAnim;
    nameFrame;
    digitsInNumber;
    countFrame;
    format;
    duration;
    loop;
    ElementDOM;

    constructor(nameAnim, nameFrame, digitsInNumber, countFrame, format, duration, loop, ElementDOM){
        this.nameAnim = nameAnim;
        this.nameFrame = nameFrame;
        this.digitsInNumber = digitsInNumber;
        this.countFrame = countFrame;
        this.format = format;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.loop = loop;
        this.ElementDOM = ElementDOM;

        this._preloadImages().then(() => {
            this._createAnim();
        });
    }

    /**
     * @private
    **/
    _preloadImages() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let loadedCount = 0;

            for (let i = 0; i <= this.countFrame; i++) {
                const paddedIndex = i.toString().padStart(this.digitsInNumber, '0');
                const imgPath = `../../assets/animation/frameAnim/${this.nameAnim}/${this.nameFrame}${paddedIndex}.${this.format}`;
                const img = new Image();

                img.src = imgPath;
                img.onload = () => {
                    loadedCount++;
                    if (loadedCount >= this.countFrame) {
                        resolve();
                    }
                };
                img.onerror = reject;
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * @private
     **/
    _createAnim() {
        const DATA_ANIM = [];

        for (let i = 0; i <= this.countFrame; i++) {
            const paddedIndex = i.toString().padStart(this.digitsInNumber, '0');
            DATA_ANIM.push({
                background: `url('../../assets/animation/frameAnim/${this.nameAnim}/${this.nameFrame}${paddedIndex}.${this.format}') no-repeat center`,
                backgroundSize: 'cover'
            })
        }

        let params = {
            duration: this.duration,
            fill: 'forwards', 
            iterations: this.loop,
        };
    
        this.anim = this.ElementDOM.animate(DATA_ANIM, params);
    }

    /**
     * @public
     **/
    deleteAnim() {
        if (this.anim) {
            this.anim.cancel();
            this.anim = null;
        }
    }
}



I do the initialization of the class like this:
const animFrame = document.querySelector(".slider_games_card_anim");
const animFrameCards = new AnimFrameAll("frameCards", "Frame_", 5, 74, "png", 6000, Infinity, animFrame);

But when the animation starts in the application, it starts blinking, or disappears altogether after 1-2 laps. In the "network" tab, I see that animation files are constantly being uploaded further (even those that have already been uploaded), although the animation is looped and the same frames are used.
